# Planetary-scale computing architectures for electronic trading: where is the data?

Tags: data

In his intriguing TED Talk, *[How algorithms shape our world](http://www.ted.com/talks/kevin_slavin_how_algorithms_shape_our_world.html)*, Kevin Slavin shows this map from "Planetary-scale computing architectures for electronic trading" ... does anyone know if this data is available online?

[image]

Comment: This graphic appears around 13:45 into the talk.  The blue dots are suggested locations for servers and yes, lots of them are in the oceans.

Comment: I think you'll have to contact the authors ([Wissner-Gross](http://www.alexwg.org/) or [Freer](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~freer/)), because the work is scheduled to appear in print soon.

Comment: @whuber, I hope they plan on water-proofing them!

Comment: @whuber emailed the author, who likely has bigger fish to fry.  Interesting how few blue dots on west coast of US.

Comment: Had a good chuckle about this one. Good observations. Would be interested to know what the author has to say.

Comment: At least the ocean keeps the servers cool...

Comment: I'm surprised [Telegeography.com](http://www.telegeography.com/telecom-resources/map-gallery/index.html) doesn't have this map.

Comment: He says the the map has been put together by mathematicians at MIT. Perhaps the data is available from the MIT direct? Doesn't look like the west coast was a part of the equation there. The theoretical server locations are probably results for fastest possible transfers algorithms for only the markets depicted by the red dots??? Perhaps they have other maps for alternate market locations?

Answer (score 2):

Found the paper on one of the author's sites:

Relativistic statistical arbitrage
A. D. Wissner-Gross, C. E. Freer

http://www.alexwg.org/publications/PhysRevE_82-056104.pdf